# How to sort number from min to max number - Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections, arraylist

How can i save numbers in List, where i could sort it from minimum to maximum.
I created new string where i insert all numbers. Than i get in in List and sort it. After that i check a number and i get colour od icon.

I tried this:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

int colour1 = 1;
int colour2 = 3;
int colour3 = 2;
int colour4 = 3;

String rezerva =colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4;
List<String> myList = new ArrayList(rezerva);
Collections.sort(myList);

colour1 = myList.get(0);

if (colour1==1){
//change icon to red
}
else if (colour1==2){
//change icon to white
}
else {
//change icon to black
}
```

Comment: Your code won't come even close to compiling at the moment. Please create a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: String rezerva = colour1, colour2,colour3,colour4; what is the meaning of this line ?

Comment: i got in String rezerva = color1 (as 1),then color2 (as 3) ans so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Integer` instead of `String` for your list

```
    Integer colour1=1;
    Integer colour2=3;
    Integer colour3=2;
    Integer colour4=3;

    ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myList.add(colour1);
    myList.add(colour2);
    myList.add(colour3);
    myList.add(colour4);
    Collections.sort(myList);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a **comparator** for your situation. And pass it as an argument to **Collection.sort()**

Comment: +1, But I think it would be better if OP encapsulated all this logic into a class that implements the `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want... but to get your integers into the list, you can try:

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4);
```

Also at the top your colours are integers, but at the bottom they look like Strings, perhaps you can rephrase your question a bit.  I think the solution will be easy.

Answer (score 3):

save numbers in list:
first of all the list should be from type int, then insert it one by one:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(colour1);
myList.add(colour2);
myList.add(colour3);
myList.add(colour4);
```

for sorting it just use:

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

and it'll work because Integer implement Comparable